# Connecting 2 android devices over internet

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I'm trying to connect 2 android device (without server in the middle, just directly like peer-to-peer) which are connected to internet(they are far apart) and send messages.

I thought its like normal socket programming, and connects via IP, seems not.

what I have done so far is this:

I have created 2 android projects, server(receiver) and client(sender)

running in 2 separate devices

Both devices are connected to internet

found the IP of the device with server app running in (using whatismyip.com) 
and used it in client app code

but when I want to send a text from client to server, an exception happens in client printing Error3

this is my code:
server:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ServerSocket ss = null;
   String mClientMsg = "";
   Thread myCommsThread = null;
   protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
   public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
    this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
    this.myCommsThread.start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
        ss.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_ID:
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            tv.setText(mClientMsg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
   };
   class CommsThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Message m = new Message();
            m.what = MSG_ID;
            try {
                if (s == null)
                    s = ss.accept();
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                String st = null;
                st = input.readLine();
                mClientMsg = st;
                myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Client (Error3):

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private Button bt;
   private TextView tv;
   private Socket socket;
   private String serverIpAddress = "5.114.22.118";
   // AND THAT'S MY DEV'T MACHINE WHERE PACKETS TO
   // PORT 5000 GET REDIRECTED TO THE SERVER EMULATOR'S
   // PORT 6000
   private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 80;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

      new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

      bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
               EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
               String str = et.getText().toString();
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
               out.println(str);
               Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               tv.setText("Error1");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               tv.setText("Error2");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               tv.setText("Error3");
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }

   class ClientThread implements Runnable {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
                 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                 socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
              } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
              }
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more appropriate as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm providing it as an answer.  Is your server connected to a router?  whatismyip.com returns the IP address of the router, not the device.

Comment: Server app is running in my phone and I turned my phones mobile data on(it's using my sim card internet) then checked the site for my IP, I think there is a router or something in my sim card internet provider.